# Reference value returns null after initialization pinia vue3

Tags: vuejs3, inertiajs, pinia

I have the following code:

```
import {UseBaseStore} from "@/Stores/UseBaseStore.js";
import {UseBalanceStore} from "@/Stores/UseBalanceStore.js";

const props = defineProps({
    'balance': Object
})

const baseStore = UseBaseStore()
baseStore.setBalance(props.balance)
baseStore.init()
```

I initialize a basestore that i want to use for initialization to prevent duplicate code but i run into a problem. With the following code:

```
import {defineStore} from "pinia";
import {ref} from "vue";
export const UseBaseStore = defineStore('BaseStore', () => {
    const balance = ref(null)

    function setBalance(balance) {
        balance.value = balance
        console.log(balance.value)
    }

    function init() {
        console.log(balance.value)
    }

    return {balance, setBalance, init}
})
```

The first console.log returns a proper object as expected but the second returns null, does anyone know why?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's an issue related to precedence and scope.  Your function is assigning to the **function parameter** named `balance`, and not the **store variable** named `balance`.  To correct the issue, give the parameter a different name

```js
const balance = ref(null)

function setBalance(newBalance) {
  balance.value = newBalance
  console.log(balance.value)
}
```